# std::thread segmentation fault

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to use threads to increase my work throughput, however, I am coming up with some weird errors that I don't know the cause of. The following is not my code, but is the minimal code that reproduces the error:

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<functional>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

const int THREADCOUNT = 2;

void Join(vector<thread>& T);
void Fac(int num, int& answer);

template<typename T>
ostream operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<T>& input)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        os << input[i] << '\t';
    }
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3) return 1;

    int start = atoi(argv[1]);
    int  end  = atoi(argv[2]);

    vector<thread> parallel(THREADCOUNT);
    vector<int> answers(end - start + 1);

    for (int n = start; n <= end; n++)
    {
        if (parallel[n % THREADCOUNT].joinable())
        {
            parallel[n % THREADCOUNT].join();
        }

        parallel[n % THREADCOUNT] = thread(Fac, n, ref(answers[n - start]));
    } //n
    Join(parallel);
    cout << answers.size() << endl;
    cout << answers << endl;
    return 0;
} //end main

void Join(vector<thread>& T)
{
    for (auto& thread : T)
    {
        if (thread.joinable()) thread.join();
    }
}

void Fac(int num, int& answer)
{
    if (num < 1) { answer = 1; return; }
    answer = 1;
    while (num != 1)
    {
        answer = num * answer;
        num--;
    }
}
```

The segmentation fault occurs when I try to retrieve the data inside the `answers` `std::vector`. I am on a *CentOS Linux 7*, and compiling with this command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o T.exe -lpthread
```

What exactly is going on? I stared at it for a while and looked at some pages on *StackOverflow* but I can't seem to understand what's going on?

Comment: Does it give the same error without multithreading?

Comment: I don't see *any* synchronization between threads/access-to-varibles here - no wonder it's blowing up. Read up on `atomic`s, `mutex`s (locks and synchronization in general).

Comment: "The following is not my code" So where is it from? You could maybe reference that source for help. Also, have you ever used threading before?

Comment: *I stared at it for a while and looked at some pages on StackOverflow but I can't seem to understand what's going on?*  -- Multithreaded programming is much more than just starting threads.  As the other comment suggested, you need to know about synchronization.

Comment: Each thread looks to be interacting with its own element in `answers` This should be independent enough.

Comment: @Trevor I wrote it. In my actual work code, the function is not Fac and there are a lot of complex loops that just obfuscated the real issue. And yes. The code was working just up until the most recent edits :(

Comment: Only hard evil I see is a missing return in operator << . Return type is wrong as well. Should be a reference.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Does it need synchronization? None of the threads touch the same resources...

Comment: There also is no error check on `end - start + 1` being `>= 0`.

Comment: @Jeff I can't reproduce if I correct your implementation of `operator<<`. Your implementation has undefined behavior. Please see if fixing your operator fixes your problem.

Comment: The algorithm won't improve performance. Each thread redoes the work of the previous threads.

Comment: @Jeff perhaps not, perhaps I was too fast. But with threads, any lack of synchronization looks instantly suspicious.

Comment: *"but is the minimal code that reproduces the error"* Are you sure? **segmentation fault** is a very common error description

Comment: @JesperJuhl especially in a case like factorial where one would expect the next iteration to build on the previous. While everything is safe and syntactically correct (excluding operator <<), the lack of synchronization should raise alarm bells that the algorithm is not quite right. Mind you I do remember seeing a lock-less multithreaded factorial on Code Review once. I'll post a link if I can find it again.

Comment: Well... That was easy: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/94591

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your function to print a vector. You need to return the stream for it to be streamable.

```
template<typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<T>& input)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        os << input[i] << '\t';
    }
    return os;
}
```